# Junit test gitlab ci cd for nextjs

Tags: next.js, gitlab-ci

**This question is for a school related team project!**

So for a school project I work in a team as the infrastructure guy.

Part of the project is a nextjs app and we need to use Junit tests.

I really want to run there junit test in the **gitlab ci cd** (preferably with **docker**) before deploying the application. Is there anyone with experience on how the **.gitlab-ci.yml** should look like to make this work.

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Note: I do not have any experience with nextjs.

Comment: Hi Laurent! I don't think you will have much luck with this question. StackOverflow is a good place for pointed questions about a specific issue. I recommend at least taking a look at the first page of this to get an idea of what is expected of a question https://stackoverflow.com/tour but with that aside, check out the gitlab-ci documentation. It really is top notch documentation. It's easy to navigate and has many examples, probably even examples for exactly what you are trying to do. I think you'll find that what you are trying to do is fairly easy to learn with their docs. Good luck!

Comment: it's not my first gitlab ci cd pipline, i'm just really struggeling to understand how nextjs works. What docker images to use and what commands to execute, I know this is not the best place but didn't find any better place to ask for help.